# Keeps detecting SELinux as enabled even though I disabled it (When trying to install FreePBX)

Tags: centos, centos-6, sip, asterisk, selinux

I was following this guide to install FreePBX on CentOS 6.9 (minimaslist), everything worked, until the last step to install FreePBX: `./install -n` from `/usr/src/freepbx`, I keep getting the follwing error msg:

```
Assuming you are Database Root
Checking if SELinux is enabled...Error!
SELinux is enabled.  Please disable SELinux before installing FreePBX.
```

I have disabled SELinux, by writing `SELINUX=disabled` in the following file `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` then rebooted, but I keep having the same problem.
For reference, here is the output of `cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux`:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Here is the output to `sestatus`

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Comment: What does `sudo sestatus` show?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Just added that to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this problem before:
A quick search made me realise that in order to disable SELinux I have to modify `/etc/selinux/config` instead, doing that gave for `sestatus`:

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```